# At what cases are we allowed to change to content of a string in c?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am having a hard time understanding how exactly are we allowed to play around with strings in c.

At class we were told that:
- If we use the definition:

```
char *str="I love dogs";
```

we are NOT allowed to change the content of the string, and writing:

```
str[0]='W'
```

will result in an error.
- If we use the definition:

```
char str[N]="I love dogs";
```

we are allowed to change the content of the string.

Will the functions in , for example strcpy, work in either case? Because I think I have seen an example where it worked.

Can anyone please explain when exactly can I change the content of a string, and why? Because now when I try to work with a string I have no idea what I am allowed to do and what not.

EDIT: Another thing, if we have:

```
char str[N]="I love dogs";
```

and we do something like

```
char *str2=str;
```

will we be able to change str2?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's very simple: if it's declared `const`, or it's a pointer to a string literal, you aren't allowed to modify it.

Comment: It's a historical mistake that string literals aren't automatically declared `const`. They fixed that in C++.

Comment: Can you please explain what will happen for the example at then end of my post? Does it count as an array or not? And why?

Comment: Of course it's an array. `char str[N]` declares an array.

Comment: `str2` is a pointer to the array, it doesn't change anything about whether the array is modifiable.

Comment: @Barmar "It's a historical mistake that string literals aren't automatically declared const"  --> _String literals_ existed years before `const`.  Changing the language to  "automatically declared const" would have broken much existing code base.  Given C is still highly use, the choice is not a _mistake_ - just an unfortunate paradigm we should have evolved out of by now.

Comment: @chux Yes, that's the history I meant -- for backward compatibility we're stuck with this unfortunate inconsistency -- they're not modifiable, but they're not `const`.